# android facebook fql thats get friends of user using my appliction

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-fql

I am using this fql to friends of my user

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square,is_app_user  FROM user WHERE uid IN " +
            "(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())";
```

When completed, I insert to array only users whose `is_app_user` is true and it works.

```
if(friend.getBoolean("is_app_user")){
friends.add(friend.getString("uid"));
            }
```

But I am sure there is a better way to do that with improved fql which modify the `where` to my app user instead of downloading all friends then check them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You add it to the WHERE clause

`SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) AND is_app_user`

Comment: i did + insted of AND  and didnt understood why it didnt worked . thanks .